# Django / Python - Convert image from AWS S3 bucket to Base64?

Tags: python, html, django, amazon-s3, base64

I'm trying to convert each image instance to base64 using images URL. All images are stored in my amazon-s3 bucket. Unfortunately, my generated encryption is not displaying the image at my recipe_plain.html template. Any help is appreciated.

**views.py**

```
...
import base64

class RecipePlainView(DetailView):
    model = Recipe
    template_name = 'recipes/recipe_plain.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RecipePlainView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        image = self.object.image
        image.open(mode='rb')
        context['recipe_image_base64'] = base64.b64encode(image.read())
        image.close()
        return context
```

**recipe_plain.html**

```
<img src="data:image;base64,{{ recipe_image_base64 }}" alt="{{ recipe.image.name }}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that context['recipe_image_base64'] variable was returning the base64 in bytes object. This has been resolved using the decode() function.

I also simplified the script using the requests library and included a validation.

```
import base64, requests

class RecipePlainView(DetailView):
    model = Recipe
    template_name = 'recipes/recipe_plain.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        url = self.object.image.url
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            byteBase64 = base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content)
            context['recipe_image_base64'] = byteBase64.decode("utf-8")
        else:
            context['recipe_image_base64'] = False

        return context
```

Answer (score -1):

For C#

```
    var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
      _settings.AccessKey, _settings.SecretKey,
      RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1
  );
            var request = new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = _settings.BucketName,
                Key = $"{_settings.BucketName}/{Request.UserId}/{Request.Filename}",
            };

            var response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
            if (response.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                byte[] bytes;
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    response.ResponseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }

                string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                var img = new GenericImg() { Imagebase64 = base64 };
                return new AusGetImage() { Image = img, Response = AuthResponse.Successful, Success = true };
            }
            return new AusGetImage() { Response = AuthResponse.NotSuccessful, Message = response.HttpStatusCode.ToString() };
```

Comment: The question asked for a solution in Python. Please do not post solutions in unrelated languages.